# What's an absorbing shield's saving throw DC?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, equipment

The *Dungeon Master Guide* describes the [*absorbing shield*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicArmor.htm#absorbingShield), saying that "it can disintegrate an object that it touches, as the spell," but the description doesn't provide a save DC against this effect. Why is that? Is the DC of that ability somehow calculated automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [*absorbing shield*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#absorbing-shield) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 221) (50,170 gp; 15 lbs.) follows the standard rules for [Saving Throws against Magic Item Powers](http://dndsrd.net/magicItems.html#saving-throws-against-magic-item-powers) (*DMG* 214) for determining the saving throw DC against its [*disintegrate*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#disintegrate) effect: 10 + the spell level of the effect the item's duplicating + the ability score modifier for the minimum ability score necessary to cast the equivalent spell.

This makes the saving throw DC against the *absorbing shield* effect 19 (10 base then +6 for a 6th-level spell then +3 for the minimum Intelligence or Charisma score of 16 needed to cast that 6th-level spell).

Also, as the *shield* is created at caster level 17, if the subject fails that saving throw, the *absorbing shield*'s *disintegrate* effect deals that subject 34d6 points of damage.